# Is there a quicker way of finding all the "simple" pathways through a network?

Tags: r, igraph

I am running a form of network analysis (looking at biological pathways) where I am trying to determine the relationships between various nodes and one "end-point" node within the system. One of the very first steps I have to do as part of this is to refine the pre-existing network down to only the nodes and connections which are related to my selected end-point (I.e. it relies on finding all the nodes within the system which are connected upstream of my chosen node).

Due to the nature of the data I am working with, I have been using the R package igraph which has the `all_simple_paths()` function which creates a list of simple pathways from a selected start point and a selected end point.

So, I will have a data set which has two parts which look like the following.

pathway_table:

```
from   to   from_name   to_name
2   4   hsa:1630   hsa:842
2   69   hsa:1630   hsa:26060
3   2   hsa:836   hsa:1630
4   3   hsa:842   hsa:839
4   529   hsa:842   hsa:840
6   170   hsa:1499   hsa:51176
```

And info_igraph:

```
IGRAPH 55e9f5a DNW- 585 2090 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), KEGGNode (v/x), weight (e/n), KEGGEdge (e/x)
+ edges from 55e9f5a (vertex names):
 [1] hsa:1630 ->hsa:842   hsa:1630 ->hsa:26060 hsa:836  ->hsa:1630 
 [4] hsa:842  ->hsa:836   hsa:842  ->hsa:840   hsa:1499 ->hsa:51176
 [7] hsa:1499 ->hsa:6932  hsa:1499 ->hsa:6934  hsa:1499 ->hsa:83439
```

I first establish every node which exist only at the start of the system, giving me a vector of starting nodes. And then I basically do a set of loops where I find all simple pathways from every start point to my one end point:

```
start_genes = which(!(pathway_table$from %in% pathway_table$to))

for (nstart in 1:length(start_genes)){

  ## Part 1 - searches for all simple pathways

  nstart_gene = pathway_table$from[start_genes[nstart]]

  smple_path_n = igraph::all_simple_paths(info_igraph,
                                    nstart_gene,
                                    to = which(igraph::vertex_attr(info_igraph)$name == geneKEGG)) # The end point remains consistent

  ## Part 2 - if a path exists from the start to the end this converts the list of connections into just a list of nodes

  if (length(smple_path_n) != 0){

    dir_paths_part = list()

    for (nsmples in 1:length(smple_path_n)){

      curr_smple = as_ids(smple_path_n[[nsmples]])
      dir_paths_part[[nsmples]] = curr_smple

    }

    dir_paths = unique(c(dir_paths, dir_paths_part))

  }
}
```

My problem is that while this works reasonably well it is a little slow and, more problematically, it does not scale particularly well. In 1/100 of the networks I am looking at there are hundreds of start points and the network has so many connections that it takes ages to search through all of them in this method (which basically does it one-by-one).

I am wondering if anyone can think of a better way to achieve the same outcome?

For a fully reproducible example of the exact issue I am having you can use the following and feed it into the above:

```
geneKEGG = "hsa:1438"

pathway_kgml =  try(KEGGgraph::retrieveKGML("hsa:hsa05200",
                                  organism = "hsa",
                                  destfile = tmp_fl,
                                  method = "wget",
                                  quiet = TRUE))

pathway_info = KEGGgraph::parseKGML2Graph(pathway_kgml,
                                 expandGenes = TRUE,
                                 genesOnly = FALSE)

pathway_table = igraph::as_long_data_frame(igraph::igraph.from.graphNEL(pathway_info))

info_igraph = igraph::igraph.from.graphNEL(pathway_info)
```

Comment: Can you explain concisely, in plain English (no code), what you want to do? You want to find all vertices from which a certain vertex is reachable?  If so, look up [`subcomponent`](https://igraph.org/r/doc/subcomponent.html). It is not necessary to find paths in the graph. Also, the term "pathway" is not standard, and it's not quite clear to me what you mean by it.

Comment: I want to find all of the nodes/vertices which are connected to my chosen node (either directly or via other nodes).

I use the term "pathway" because the networks I am working with are directional (which is important for my project). I.e. I only want to include nodes which are connected to my selected node in an "inward" direction.

In simpler terms, I am looking for every "route" through the network, towards my selected node and I wish the output to be a data frame of every connection (I.e. a ```from``` and ```to``` column with nodes in both.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. First you say "I want to find all of the nodes/vertices ..." (which is solved by `subcomponent`). Then you say "I am looking for every 'route'" and "I wish the output to be a data frame of every connection". Do you want to find vertices, paths or connections? It's not clear.

Comment: It's best if you show a concrete example. Take this graph: `g<-make_graph(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 1, 7, 5, 5, 1))`. What is your expected output for the target node `5`?  Feel free to show it through a simpler example.

Comment: So, if you were to use the ```all_simple_paths(g, from = 1, to = 5)``` function from my code that would basically show you an example of the output. It looks like a list of vertices: ```[[1]] 1 2 3 5``` If the network had more connections you might see something like: ```[[1]] 1 2 3 5 [[2]] 1 2 8 9 5 [[3]] 1 2 8 10 5``` From this you can then extract all the unique nodes which connect to ```5``` but you also get a list of the simple paths/"routes".

Comment: Hopefully that's a little clearer?

Comment: I think you should edit your question, make it much shorter and much more focused on a single specific problem. The question is not highlighted at the moment. It sounds like your problem is that `all_simple_paths` is too slow, but otherwise you want to do exactly what what `all_simple_paths` does. There is no solution to this. There will be an explosively high number of simple paths in a graph. If your analysis technique relies on listing all of them, it will only be usable with tiny graphs. The only reasonable solution is to come up with a different analysis technique.